# selecting objects by attribute or type from a group of objects

Tags: java, search, data-structures

Imagine I have a group of complex objects, let's say they have a first name, last name, and color.

I want to retrieve a selection of all objects in that group that are red, and have a last name that starts with "K".

does java include a data structure that I can store these objects in that allows for this kind of selection? Is there an elegant solution to this that doesn't involve writing a bunch of for loops?

I'd like to do this without using any of the java database libraries.

Comment: You can implement it youself. Some custom collection that will also store indexes based on required properties. When object is being added it's scanned for properties values and stores a reference to the added object in index collections. Each index collection can be implemented as `Map<Object, Set<Object>>`, where the key is property value and set - is collection of objects that share same property value.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no data structure in Java which will let you do these operations out of box. You would need something like an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) to make this work. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) allows you to do all the search operations that you have just said very efficiently. I believe it also has an In-Memory store, so it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The project http://www.glazedlists.com/ has a GroupingList which let you group the elements of a List over your own Comparator. Here the link to GroupingList: http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/GroupingList.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample just off the top of my head (I didn't implement remove methods):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class IndexedCollection<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    private Map<String, Map<Object, Set<E>>> indices = new HashMap<String,  Map<Object, Set<E>>>();

    public IndexedCollection(String...indices) {
        for (String index: indices) {
            this.indices.put(index, new HashMap<Object, Set<E>>());
        }
    }

    public boolean add(E entry) {
        try {
                Map<String, Object> objectIndices = collectIndices(entry);

                for (Entry<String, Object> objectIndex: objectIndices.entrySet()) {
                    Map<Object, Set<E>> map = this.indices.get(objectIndex.getKey());
                    Set<E> set = map.get(objectIndex.getValue());

                    if (set == null) {
                        set = new HashSet<E>();
                        map.put(objectIndex.getValue(), set);
                    }

                    set.add(entry);
                }

                return super.add(entry);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to collect object indices", e);
        }
    };

    public Set<E> findByIndex(String name, Object value) {
        Map<Object, Set<E>> index = this.indices.get(name);

        if (index != null)
            return index.get(value);

        return null;
    }

    public Set<E> findByIndices(Index...indices) {
        Set<E> results = null;

        for (Index index: indices) {
            Set<E> tmp = findByIndex(index.name, index.value);

            if (tmp.size() == 0)
                return null;

            if (results == null)
                results = tmp;
            else {
                Set<E> newResult = new HashSet<E>();
                for (E value: results) {
                    if (tmp.contains(value))
                        newResult.add(value);
                }

                results = newResult;
}
        }

        return results;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> collectIndices(E e) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Map<String, Object> indices = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Field[] fields = e.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field: fields) {
            if (this.indices.containsKey(field.getName())) {
                boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
                field.setAccessible(true);
                indices.put(field.getName(), field.get(e));
                field.setAccessible(accessible);
            }
        }

        return indices;
    }

    public static class Index {
        private String name;
        private Object value;

        public Index(String name, Object value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```